# Fixing IE7 weird float behaviour

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7, css-float

There are already many IE7 floating questions here.

I have read some of them but still can't find a fix to my problem.

If you view this page in IE8, Firefox and Chrome.

http://pastehtml.com/view/1devx12.html

They all display correctly.

But if you view it in IE7, it looks like this,

http://img713.imageshack.us/i/ietesterie7.jpg/

All labels display on the first line, which is obviously not what is expected.

I would like to avoid adding extra html markup if possible.

What css should be added to fix the problem?

Many thanks to you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try styling your checkboxes a little differently. Wrap the label around the input - this will keep them together. Also, instead of having them in a DIV, try styling them in an unordered list.

See live demo here (haven't tested in IE -haven't got it installed on Mac- but should work): http://jsfiddle.net/wG7B2/

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <label for="checkbox1"><input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="">Option1</label>
    </li>
    <li><label for="checkbox2"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" value="">Option2</label>
    </li>
    <li><label for="checkbox3"><input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" value="">Option3</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

ul li{
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

ul li:last-child{
    padding-bottom:0px;
}

ul li input{
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

Comment: It seems there is no easy way without adding altering the html markup. But this should be fine as long as it works on IE7. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: No worries @bobo. Best of luck with it.